# Как сделать плавное появление картинки при открытии сайта впервые на css?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, анимация

На шапке сайта имеется картинка и я хочу ,чтобы при открытии сайта у пользователя эта картинка плавно появлялась на экране вместо грубой обычной загрузки. 
Как это можно реализовать без использования js только на html + css?
Буду признателен за помощь.
[image: сайт]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 200px;
  background: #bfbfbf;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  animation-name: Appearance;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.1,-.6,.2,0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes Appearance {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@-o-keyframes Appearance {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes Appearance {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes Appearance {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://cache.kwork.ru/files/portfolio/t1_r/16/cover-255168-1544029616.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```